# Why women have high Erythrocyte sedimentation rate?

Tags: hematology, red-blood-cell

Why ESR (Erythrocyte sedimentation rate) 
1. higher in women
2. increases with age 
3. increases in pregnancy, infection, malignancies

**what I thought so far** : since women are menstruating so there shall be some blood loss and this might be related to that.
For age I have no clue and in pregnancy might be related to fact the mass of rbc increases during pregnancy.

But is that right ? and what about  2 and 3 ?

Comment: I have already shown an attempt at the question